# Using an ASP .NET form on an extranet to capture AD credentials, authenticate, and then work in AD mode

Tags: asp.net

I have spent about 6 hours trying to figure this out and I feel like I'm close but can't quite get the right answer. I have an extranet ASP .NET site. In that site I have an landing page that exists under a folder that has anonymous access. On that page, I have a custom login page to ask the user for a username, domain, and password that corresponds to an AD account that exists on the server. I want to take that information authenticate it against the AD on that box, and then somehow pass the AD authentication token back to the browser/client, and forward them onto the other folders on this site that requires the user to be authenticated with windows auth.

I already have code working to validate the user information successfully against AD. I just can't figure out how I pass a context or token back to the browser, set it, and then direct the user onto the part of the site that requires this windows authentication to have already taken place.

I've seen a million forms talking about using various methods of FormsAuthentication objects to store a cookie, etc - but that doesn't seem to address what I'm trying to do. I  control the logon process instead of the user seeing the standard gray windows logon box. And once I authenticate, I need to in a single place on my custom login page pass that token back to the client so for the rest of the session, it's authenticated with AD. Just as if I had received the standard windows AD prompt and correctly authenticated.

Seems like this should be possible? Any guidance is much appreciated! I'm pulling my hair out over this one!